# Fill whole space of <li> with <a> including a floating <span>

Tags: html, css

My problem:
[image: red]

I would like the red questionmark in the 2nd "a" to expand the parent li's height. As you can see it now is positioned in the 3rd anchor's line

Usually you add a display:block to the "a" and the "a" expands across the whole li, but this floating span makes some problems. While it works if the span has enough space in the same line with some text of the anchor text it does not expand the li if the span is alone in a new line.

As the anchor text is not limited in length, I cannot set a height property to li or a, I can set it for the span, but that does not solve the problem. I tried to change the span to a div, but I did not find a solution.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cabzo3/1/).

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">text <span> ok </span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">long long long long text <span  class="woot"> ?</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#">short text <span> ok </span></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
      width:130px
}
a {
      display:block;
}
span {
      float:right;
      display:block;
}

/************************************/
/****Just for better visibility****/
.woot {  
      color:red;
}
li a:hover {
      background:grey;
}
li  {  
      background:lightgrey;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I can get the li to include the problematic span by adding a div around each li, but my original problem was that in this case the background of the li cannot be styled, as still the empty line (with only the span floating on right side) does not get the li background.

Comment: Why did you make it float right ? Remove this and you're done... Or maybe your question is not clear enough

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to flow on the right side, as the span has some additional styling and it looks good aligned on the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a class on the parent `a` element and give a padding to it :

```
a.wooted {
    padding-right: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then you just position absolute your question mark to the bottom right of it :

```
.woot {
    color:red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp8s98aw/)

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I have to check if I'm ok with the whole anchor text being padded on the right side, as the absolute positioning removes the element from the flow.

Comment: Thanks, this will do it for me now. I just thought there might be some solution without breaking the flow (with position absolute).

Comment: Still a small drawback...the information in the span on the right is not allowed to be dynamic in length, as then I have to reserve space for the maximum possible content length = make the padding large enough to fit the longest span content without overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [word-break: break-all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) in you `li` elements:

```css
div {
    width:130px
}
a {
    display:block;
}
.woot {
    color:red;
}
span {
    float:right;
}
li a:hover {
    background:grey;
}
li {
    background:lightgrey;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">text<span> ok</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">long long long long text <span class="woot"> ?</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">short text<span > ok</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This "solves" the problem, but on the cost of words being cut in parts. The word "long" becomes lon + g on new line... ok and it even does not solve..